# Behavior’s Gallery crash when it invokes requestFocus

Tags: android, crash, request, android-gallery

Depending on the position of the gallery, one or another edittext is to receive focus. Althought I could do it, behavior's gallery crashs: When Gallery run a position and set focus on edittext, Gallery's velocity crashes. It seems as if Gallery was too slow to get the request on time .

I've not found any significant information about it.

```
galleryView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AdapterView adapterView,
            View view, int pos, long l) {

        if (pos == 0) {
            pie_foto_1.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pie_foto_1.requestFocus();
                }
            });
        }

        if (pos == 1) {
            pie_foto_2.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pie_foto_2.requestFocus();
                }
            });
        }

        if (pos == 2) {

            pie_foto_3.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pie_foto_3.requestFocus();
                }
            });

            pie_foto_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pie_foto_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pie_foto_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AdapterView adapterView
    ) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gallery needs more time to get its new position. So I put a delay before Gallery changes position in order to get a nice transition.

```
                               else if (pos == 1)
                                {
                                    Runnable mMyRunnable = new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            pie_foto_1.post(new Runnable() {
                                                public void run() {
                                                    pie_foto_2.requestFocus();
                                                    // headline.clearFocus();

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    };

                                    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
                                    myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable, 100);
                                }
```